# Blue highlighting not appear with custom UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview, highlight, uimenuitem

I created a subclass of UITextView to add a custom UIMenuItem. The problem is that when I press my custom action to display custom item, the text is not highlighted. Any idea?

[image]

**ActionsTextView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ActionsDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)addDreamSignalWithText:(NSString *)text range:(NSRange)range;

@end

@interface ActionsTextView : UITextView

#pragma mark - Delegate
@property IBOutlet id<ActionsDelegate>actionsDelegate;

#pragma mark - Methods
- (void)addDreamSignalAction:(id)sender;

@end
```

**ActionsTextView.m**

```
#import "ActionsTextView.h"

@implementation ActionsTextView

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {

    if (action == @selector(addDreamSignalAction:)) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;

}

#pragma mark - Methods
- (void)addDreamSignalAction:(id)sender {

    if ([_actionsDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(addDreamSignalWithText:range:)]) {
        [_actionsDelegate addDreamSignalWithText:[self.text substringWithRange:self.selectedRange]
                                           range:self.selectedRange];
    }

    // Deselect text
    self.selectedTextRange = nil;

}


@end
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Why do you expect the text to be fully selected just because the menu is presented?

Comment: @rmaddy, the normal behavior is: "Press" -> "Show initial menu with select option" -> "Press select" -> "Custom action". That is, I want to avoid initial selection stage. Directly select the text and show "Custom action"

Comment: You'll have to add your own code to select the text.

Comment: rmaddy, yes, but where? I tried variety of methods, but all have strange behaviors

Comment: Look into the `UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification` notification.

Comment: rmaddy, works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to rmaddy, I found the solution.
Here is the code:

**ActionsTextView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ActionsDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)addDreamSignalWithText:(NSString *)text range:(NSRange)range;

@end

@interface ActionsTextView : UITextView

#pragma mark - Delegate
@property IBOutlet id<ActionsDelegate>actionsDelegate;

#pragma mark - Methods
- (void)addDreamSignalAction:(id)sender;

#pragma mark - Notifications
- (void)menuControllerWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification;

@end
```

**ActionsTextView.m**

```
#import "ActionsTextView.h"

@implementation ActionsTextView

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {

    if (action == @selector(addDreamSignalAction:)) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;

}

#pragma mark - Methods
- (void)addDreamSignalAction:(id)sender {

    if ([_actionsDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(addDreamSignalWithText:range:)]) {
        [_actionsDelegate addDreamSignalWithText:[self.text substringWithRange:self.selectedRange]
                                           range:self.selectedRange];
    }

    // Deselect text
    self.selectedTextRange = nil;

}

#pragma mark - Notifications
- (void)menuControllerWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {

    if (self.selectedRange.length == 0) {

        [self select:self];

    }

}

@end
```